# Assigning all check items into a variable

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

Is it possible to assign all the values from checked items in a single variable ? If radio button have this code `.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`, what about the checkboxes. Here's my xml layout for checkboxes.

```
<CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbFacilities"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Facility1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbFacilities2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Facility2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbFacilities3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Facility3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Meaning if I check all items and assign it to variable `x`. `x = Facility1` , `Facility2` and `Facility3` ?

```
String rg1 = "*";
                                String rg2 = "*";
                                String rg4 = "*";
                                String rg5 = "*";
                                theFilter[5] = "0";
                                if (cbRegAffil.isChecked()) {
                                    int reg = rgRegAffil
                                            .getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                                    RadioButton rBtReg = (RadioButton) dia
                                            .findViewById(reg);
                                    rg1 = (String) rBtReg.getText();

                                }
                                if (cbAdmin.isChecked()) {
                                    int adm = rgAdmin
                                            .getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                                    RadioButton rBtAdm = (RadioButton) dia
                                            .findViewById(adm);
                                    rg2 = (String) rBtAdm.getText();
                                }

                                if (cbAmbience.isChecked()) {
                                    int amb = rgAmbience
                                            .getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                                    RadioButton rBtAmbience = (RadioButton) dia
                                            .findViewById(amb);
                                    rg4 = (String) rBtAmbience.getText();
                                }
                                if (cbTuition.isChecked()) {
                                    theFilter[5] = spin.getSelectedItem()
                                            .toString();
                                }
                                if (cbSpecialty.isChecked()) {
                                    int spec = rgSpecialty
                                            .getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                                    RadioButton rBtSpec= (RadioButton) dia
                                            .findViewById(spec);
                                //  rg5 = (String) rBtSpec.getText();

                                }
                                if (cbFacilities.isChecked()||cbFacilities2.isChecked()||cbFacilities3.isChecked()) {
                //**I want to assign the values checked here with the variable rg5**
                                }
```

As you notice Im assigning radiobutton value into a variable, this time in the last part of the program, the value of cbFacilities1-3 if they're checked will assign to a single variable that holds string values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think you could do an array of booleans which hold the answers.

Could look like this :

```
boolean[] checkboxAnswers = new boolean[3];
checkboxAnswers[0] = checkbox1.getChecked();
checkboxAnswers[1] = checkbox2.getChecked();
checkboxAnswers[2] = checkbox3.getChecked();
```

Comment: is radiobutton counted as checkbox ?

Comment: I've edited my post , and getting errors , confilicting with String and boolean .
if I use rg5 = checkboxAnswers

Comment: Getting errors with boolean sir , if I use rg5 = checkboxAnswers confilicting with String and also getChecked does not acquiring the value .